# How to view a git branch ONLY back to the point where it was branched off?

Tags: git

I noticed when I'm on a branch (we'll call it `feat-123`) that's only a couple commits in, `git log` shows the whole history of the branch I branched from (`develop`). Is there some way to show the log only as far back as the point from which `feat-123` was created?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that `feat-123` was branched from `develop`, you can use double-dot `..` syntax to limit `git log` output to only those commits in `feat-123` that aren't also in `develop`:

```
git log --oneline --graph develop..feat-123
```

To learn more about double-dot and other helpful commit filtering syntaxes, see

1. [Revision Selection - Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges) from the [**FREE online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book).
2. [Git Revisions - Specifying Ranges](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_ranges) from the [official Linux Kernel Git documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/).

Answer (score 2):

To see a list of which commits are on one branch but not another, use git log:

```
   git log oldbranch ^newbranch --no-merges
```

Show commit logs for all commits on oldbranch that are not on newbranch.

Also, You can list multiple branches to include and exclude, e.g.

```
   git log oldbranch1 oldbranch2 ^newbranch1 ^newbranch2 --no-merges
```

Comment: This returned no results for me. I did `git log master ^my-feature --no-merges`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no shorthand for "find *any* point where history rejoins", so you have to use something like what [Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667179/1256452) and [D4NI3LS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18667256/1256452) suggested: explicitly stop logging at-or-before such a point.

There is, however, a way to automate this.  It can be encapsulated in a "one line" shell script:

```
git log HEAD --not $(
    git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads/ |
    grep -v "^$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)$"
) "$@"
```

How this works:

- The innermost bit, `git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD`, prints the current branch name, or nothing at all if you are not on a branch ("detached HEAD" state).
- We turn this into a grep pattern by adding `^` (anchor at start-of-line) and `$` (anchor at end).
- We use that to *remove* the current branch (if any) from `git for-each-ref` output.
- The `for-each-ref` output is the short refname for every branch, i.e., every ref in `refs/heads/`.  Thus, if your complete set of branch names are, for instance, `monty`, `python`, `flying`, and `circus` and you're on branch `flying`, this lists `monty`, `python`, and `circus`.
- Finally, we give all of this to `--not`, after asking `git log` to start at `HEAD`.  The `log` command uses `git rev-list` to start from wherever you ask it, and keep going backwards until something (in this case, the `--not` list) makes it stop. And of course we add `"$@"` so that any other command-line arguments are included.

Since it's a one liner, it can be embedded in `~/.gitconfig`, as an `alias`:

```
[alias]
        ltf = !git log HEAD --not $(git for-each-ref \
                --format='%(refname:short)' refs/heads | \
                grep -v "^$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD)$")
```

and now `git ltf`, `git ltf --oneline`, etc., all do the trick.  (I don't know if I like the name `ltf`, it stands for "log to fork" but this is more of a "log to join".  Maybe `lbr` for "log branch"?)

Comment: The alias may need a terminating `--` (after the final close bracket) to ensure that the refs are discriminated from possible filenames. to avoid the error fatal: ambiguous argument 'Documentation': both revision and filename Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'. Plus the final `"$@"` hasn't been copied into the alias (but again may conflict with the `--` placement).

Comment: The alias has the side effect of acting like the `"$@"` is already in there.  I didn't want a terminating `--` as I want to allow more options to `log`, e.g., `--oneline`.  On the other hand the `--not` is still in effect, maybe there should be a second `--not` to cancel it out...

Comment: I'll try that (`--not`) out. I wasn't aware of the alias `"$@"` action. Thanks.