# How to know name of source branch in Git

Tags: git

I am new to Git. I am now working on a branch named **fixes**. Actually I have forgotten from where I have cut the branch. So is there any way in Git so that I can know my source branch name.

Comment: Should be `master`. Run `git branch` to see list of all branches.

Comment: You can use pretty graphing or a tool like SourceTree (disclaimer: I'm somewhat affiliated with the latter).

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667163/how-to-view-a-git-branch-only-back-to-the-point-where-it-was-branched-off/18667256#18667256

Comment: See alsp [Find the parent branch of a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161204/find-the-parent-branch-of-a-branch), and [Branch length: where does a branch start in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581026/branch-length-where-does-a-branch-start-in-git), and [Find which branch is used to create current branch in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665780/find-which-branch-is-used-to-create-current-branch-in-git).

Answer (score 8):

You can run 'gitk --all' and visually track your branch down to where it was branched off.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using github there's a network view for a repository that will show the history of all the branches. That will show you from which branch the current branch originally stemmed.

Answer (score 0):

Branches in Git do not track (by themselves) from which commit they were created, because if you follow their parent references all the way, you'll eventually just reach the root commit.

You could infer from which branch or commit a branch was created by using various tools in Git, such as `merge-base`.